# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable for SendKeys

Tags: python, python-2.7

I write this simple script that opens the Google page and writes in the search bar but it only opens the URL and reports an error in prompt. Can someone explain were I'm going wrong?

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new_tab("http://www.google.com")

import win32api, win32con
import SendKeys
x = range(1,4)
for count in x:
    SendKeys('a', 0)
```

The prompt response

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\SCRIPT\python\openandwrite.py", line 8, in <module>
    SendKeys('{a}', 0)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Try `SendKeys.SendKeys('a', 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `SendKeys` is the module, you want to access the class within that module:

```
SendKeys.SendKeys('a', 0)
```

Alternatively, bring the class in directly:

```
from SendKeys import SendKeys
```

Comment: Thank you now it run but write in the prompt but I expected that write in the search bar. Some suggestion?

Comment: @user3535205 nothing specific, but you will need to switch focus to the webbrowser window